# Need to only return what's in the if-statement, but get an error with only one return statement

Tags: java, return-type

For my program, I'm trying to just return the value of index, which is equal to i. Except Java won't let me return just that if-statement without an error message. I added a return index statement at the end of my code, but this just adds a zero to the end of the index value. I just want to return the value of index, which is i.

Here is the code I have:

```
 public static int missingValue(int[] X)
        {
            int index = 0;
            // X is an array with 9 integers from 0 to 9, like in the puzzle
            // need a boolean array to mark values found in the row
            
            
            boolean[] foundValues = {false, false, false, false, false, false,
                    false, false, false, false};
            
            // need a for loop to locate the 0 as well as mark off the
            // locations of found values
            for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                foundValues[X[i]] = true;
                
            }
            //need another for loop to see which value is missing
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (!foundValues[i] == true)
                {
                    index = i;
                    
                }
            }
        return index; 
        }
```

I tried just returning i, which didn't work. It gave me the error that an int method must return an int, even though i is an int value. I tried not initializing index, but then when I tried to return index, I received an error that index must be initialized before it can be returned, so I initialized index to zero. Initializing it to zero has it adding a zero to whatever the value i is when I tried running the program.

Comment: What do you want `missingValue` to return if you haven't found a value?

Comment: And what exactly does "adding a zero to whatever the value i is" mean? Please edit your question to include a complete, runnable example which illustrates the question.

Comment: In general, you don't need to compare a `boolean` against a `true` or `false` constant.  It's redundant. If `foo` is a `boolean` variable,  then `if (foo == true)` is the same as `if (foo)` and `if (foo == false)` is the same as `if (!foo)`. A statement like `if (!foo == true)`  can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```java
 public static int missingValue(int[] X){
            int index = 0;
            // X is an array with 9 integers from 0 to 9, like in the puzzle
            // need a boolean array to mark values found in the row
            
            
            boolean[] foundValues = {false, false, false, false, false, false,
                    false, false, false, false};
            
            // need a for loop to locate the 0 as well as mark off the
            // locations of found values
            for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                foundValues[X[i]] = true;
                
            }
            //need another for loop to see which value is missing
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (!foundValues[i])
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        return -1; 
  }
```

should just work.

Java doesn't know that exactly one value is missing.
So you need to cover the case when none is missing. In this case the classic approach would be to return `-1`. However you could also throw an Exeption.
This method only returns the lowest missing value because it returns after that.

Another problem with this code is, that you are not checking if `0` is missing in the second for-loop. The above code does.

Alternatively you can use following code for the last part (returns `9` if no missing value found):

```java
//need another for loop to see which value is missing
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    index = i;
    if (!foundValues[i])
    {
       break;
    }
}
return index;
```

I wasn't quite sure what you want to achive reading your question.

Comment: Ah, sorry! It's part of a large programming project I'm completing for a class. This is just one section of code out of 200 lines and the only code I'm still struggling to debug. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mauimeow23 if this answer helped, accept it or provide more information

Answer (score 0):

So the code works as is. That's not the problem. The problem is that you have to do:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
     if (!foundValues[i] == true)
     {
         index = i;                   
     }
 }
```

And then return the index, instead of just doing:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
     if (!foundValues[i] == true)
     {
         return i;
     }
 }
```

The reason is pretty simple. The compiler have NO IDEA what's going to be in that array. What happens if you get say, an empty array? That's perfectly legal according to what you've told the compiler. If you do that, you'll not get a hit on *any* index, and there will be no return statement. What should be returned then? There's no telling.

Therefore the compiler refuses to compile, because the code you've written cannot guarantee that it'll return anything. But if you put a variable outside the loop, initialize it to 0, run the loop, and then return the variable, you're guaranteed to return a proper value.

Now a thing you could do if you wanted to is to throw an exception if you get past the loop. You're never supposed to get out of the loop, so it's an error. It would be as simple as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!foundValues[i] == true) {
        return i;
    }
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find any missing digit, so we have an error in our input.");
```

That way, the compiler is satisfied: If it finds something in the loop, it returns, and if it doesn't, it throws an exception, which it is also okay with.

Comment: As noted by [@OldDogProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5103317/old-dog-programmer) above, it's redundant to write `if (foundValues[i] == true)`. Just write `if (foundValues[i])`. And `if (!foundValues[i] == true)` should simply be `if (!foundValues[i])`.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the question. the question was just "why can't I return in the loop".

Comment: Indeed, that wasn't the question. But if you are going to provide an answer, it's advisable to not repeat someone else's code smell as part of the answer.